# How to set height for a textfield in size inspector

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i created a UITextField of type rounded textfield, using Interface Builder,so in order to set the Height of a textfield its window was disabled(not to set any height manually) in SizeInspector.so if we want to set height manually,what procedure should we follow.

One thing i would like to mention is ,we can do that in coding part,but what i would like to know is ,how can we acheive that in interfacebuilder.

Answers from you were always appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't set the Height of a UITextField using Interface Builder. You will have to set it programatically and be sure it doesn't break any rules from [iPhone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Actually, you can set the height for any UITextField that doesn't have the `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` style. If you change it you can resize in IB.

Comment: Actually there is a way to achieve this, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35018308/3340702).

Comment: You can set the height with constraints.

Answer (score 14):

Change the border style, like this:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Yes. But it forces the text to vertically align from the center

Answer (score 2):

You can change the height of `UITextField` by editing the .xib file. Just open it using Textedit or Dashcode and search for the `IBUITextField`. Edit to `NSFrame` parameter to whatever size u want.

Answer (score 1):

increase the size of the font and the box's height will increase

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I increase the text size and the height stays fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Border Style property of the text field to something other than the rounded rectangle.  After that you can freely set the height of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on .xib file and click on "Open As"-> "Source Code". Then search for UITextField's NSFrame. Change the height as you want.

Comment: The best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

Successful solution with my condition:
After trying all above ways, I could not change the height of `UITextField`.
Finally, I found out that I put `UITextField` in stack view (or it was affected by some constraints).

So, I added `Height Constraint` for `UITextField` then put my expected height in `Constant` of Constraint.
And it works.
Specially, it works for all Border-style (None, Line, Bezel, RoundedRect).
No code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around, I realized that UITextField can be thought of as a UIButton (Rounded rect style) with a UILabel on top of it. Or, it is a UITextView on top of UIButton Rounded rect style. The number of lines, dimensions and position of the label inside the button can be easily adjusted in IB.

In my case, I wanted a read only text-field so I used UILabel on top of UIButton. I adjusted the size of button as per requirement and also label size. I also had to uncheck the 'Enable' box for the button in IB so that it does not get highlighted on touching.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change that using source code. Just right click on your storyboard, open it as source code, then search for your text field and change the height.

Comment: That is the easiest way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that i have found to accomplish this is to change the border style and then edit the other attributes to your liking. Here's an example.

```
emailField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
emailField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
emailField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
emailField.alpha = .75f;
emailField.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

![image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved textfield (with rounded rect) height problem. You must define height constraint for your textfield object.

Define height constraint for Textfield.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can change height of Text Field with any type of border style other than rounded rectangle by simply dragging. But for the Rounded Rectangle Text fields it is not possible...of course we can change height using some code.

And here I found a simple way. It worked for me

1. Select the text field and at the below right corner we can see the pins option..
2. There select the height constrain it is 30 pre-defined...
3. select that height and you can see "Add 1 Constraint" is enabled.
4. Click on that..therefore we have added height constraint for that text field.
5. Now go to the size inspector. There find the Height constraint in "Constraints"...which is above the "Content Hugging Priority"
6. You can edit the height there...give whatever value you want to give. Now see the textfield it is changed to its height which you have given.

It worked for me :) Can use this scenario for UISwitch, Segment, etc..

Answer (score 0):

As @peterdoesco.de said, Just add an Height constraint, and change it's value, this can works fine.