# How to change textfield height for an ipad using interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, interface-builder, textfield

We're using Interface Builder for developing an app for the iPad and we can't figure out how to increase the height of the textfields.

When we were using IB to develop an application for osx, you could go to the textfields attributes and under the control section you could set line break to word wrap instead of clip.

When we try to use Interface Builder for iPad applications though, it doesn't have the option of changing linebreak style under attributes-->control.

Is there any way to set the height using Interface Builder or do you have to set that in the code?

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the height of the rounded-style text field is locked in Interface Builder. My solution was to use another of the `UITextField` styles in my XIB and then call `textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` in my `viewDidLoad` method.

Of course, `textField` should be the name of the `UITextField IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 6):

iOS `UITextField`s are single line only and have a fixed height.

If you want a multi-line, variable-height text entry field then use `UITextView`.

Answer (score 5):

1 - Right click on your storyboard/xib file and select "Open as" -> "Source code".

2 - Find the xml tag relative to your TextField, e.g.

```
<textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" tag="102" contentMode="scaleToFill" misplaced="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" text="6872" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="Password" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Dxw-lR-kq5">
<rect key="frame" x="20" y="337" width="335" height="30"/>
```

3 - Change the `height` value to what you want (e.g. 50)

4 - Right click again on you storyboard and select "Open as" -> "Interface builder"

5 - See the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there is a wrapping text field,that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

set the frame of ui textfield object in view did load but it will involve  coding

```
[self.searchText setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 450, 400, 250)];
//in my case the object was called search text...
```

Comment: you can change the textfield height through xib i xcode 4.2...i did it

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the height of any UITextfield in IB.Just set the constraint in IB.Select the constraint.In the **Size Inspector**-->**Select and Edit** just change the constant to your desired value.Press Enter ...Done!!!! (Can't get multiline though)